# Remove top and bottom spacing in TextView

Tags: android, layout, textview

How do I remove the spacing on the top and bottom of the texts? I want to the two texts to touch each other or at least reduce the spacing between the texts.

I've looked at other posts recommending setting `android:includeFontPadding="false"`, but that does not work.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="96sp"
    android:text="TEXT1"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="96sp"
    android:text="TEXT2"
    android:background="@color/secondaryColor"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView" />
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: Using `android:includeFontPadding="false"` does reduce the spacing a little, although not completely. The remaining space is actually needed when displaying some characters (try `çÉ`, it reaches the top and the bottom) If you still want to get rid of that space, you can do it by customizing spacing, like setting a top padding on the second text. If you want to keep the background though you'll need to make a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that's not just empty space - it's the ascent and descent for the font, where things like the lower part of a **g** goes. The `TextView` has to have that space because it doesn't know you're not going to be using it. `includeFontPadding` affects some accents on top of the ascent, so you can remove a little bit of the space, but the rest of it's required.

Short of getting a font with no ascent and descent, honestly I think the best thing you can do is constrain the top of the lower `TextView` to the **top** of the upper one, and add a `marginTop` value that shifts it down where you want it. Use an *sp* value instead of *dp* so it stays relative to the user's font size preferences - and if you change the font you'll need to tweak it. And the backgrounds will have to be separate, behind the textviews, if you're using those

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want this at any cost, then you can do the following, I have not checked if it will work on different screen sizes . But you can attach both of their top to the same view, can be parent, then make the background transparent, if you chose different colours then this wont work, keep the text in all caps so that the regular alphabets can't go any higher or lower. Keep the margin according to the text size which you will give in dp. This is probably "I want this in any way" approach rather than an acceptable approach.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="95dp"
        android:text="TEXT1"
        
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="TEXT2"
        android:textSize="95dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: The output looks like this]

Answer (score -1):

You can do some clever stuff with a `Space` view to make this work:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
    [other TextView stuff]
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
<Space android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView2"
    [other TextView stuff]
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/space"/>
```

Then fiddle with the margin parameter in the `Space` view until the text is where you want it.

Comment: There is absolutely no valid reason to use a `Space` when using `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Please demonstrate how to do it then.  Keep in mind, negative margins are not supported.